# Rounded color picker: how to place text label in the center with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've created this color picker label and would like to place the text in the middle of it. Any thoughts on how to make it work with CSS?

Color picker example: https://jsfiddle.net/heyjs/e1sqydjm/6/

I tried `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` but it doesn't work. I would like the text label to be in the middle of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you. use `display:flex` property for that

https://jsfiddle.net/ponsiva/n4q7zfe2/3/

```css
#colorpick {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.colorpick-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: turquoise;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.colorpick-label:hover,
#colorpick:focus+.colorpick-label {
  border-color: black;
}

#colorpick:active+.colorpick-label {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="color-picker">
  <input type="color" id="colorpick" name="colorpick" value="#55aaff">
  <label for="colorpick" class="colorpick-label">Select a color:</label>
</div>
```